# File NOT set as sparse but sparse attribute is seen set on windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sparsefile, fsutil

There is a test file in windows machine where it is seen having sparse file attribute (P). But suing `fsutil sparse queryflag` says the file is not sparse. Even `queryrange` range says the same.

This is seen in multiple machines and restarting machine/windows explorer does not help.

I would like to understand the discrepancy on this behavior.

[image]

Comment: Is the folder synced with OneDrive? Files in my OneDrive folders exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: @KeithMiller No OneDrive is not installed in the server.

Comment: strange. I tried `fsutil sparse setflag file` and `fsutil sparse setrange` but the P flag isn't shown in explorer